# Trying to handle JSON and FORM posts with Pojo objects in Jersey

Tags: java, json, jersey

I am trying to handle a JSON and FORM post with jersey in combination with jsr 303 validation on the pojo object

```
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_HTML})
public Response registration(@Valid User registration) {
    UserServiceWrapper.getImpl().registrateUser(registration);
    return Response.ok(registration).build();
}
```

Currently everything is running fine for the json, but form post fail with;

> HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

I have no idea how to fix this, and keep the POJO object in the interface. anyone a idea?

Comment: please post the `form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is not supported by the default jersey 2.0 framework, the fix for this is to create your own MessageBodyReader, see below;

```
@Provider
public class FormDataReader implements MessageBodyReader<Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return mediaType.isCompatible(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
    }

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        String queryString = IOUtils.toString(entityStream);

        Object result = type.newInstance();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(result, getUrlParameters(queryString));
        return result;
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getUrlParameters(String queryString)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String param : queryString.split("&")) {
            String pair[] = param.split("=");
            String key = URLDecoder.decode(pair[0], "UTF-8");
            String value = "";
            if (pair.length > 1) {
                value = URLDecoder.decode(pair[1], "UTF-8");
            }
            params.put(new String(key), new String(value));
        }
        return params;
    }

}
```